# Lendo strings e salvando-as em arrays

Tags: java

Estou a tentar fazer um programa em que têm que ser lidos os nomes de vendedores e têm que ser armazenados num array.

O meu maior problema é que eu não sei qual é o limite de nomes inseridos pelo utilizador. Daí ter utilizado o while:

```js
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
  String seller = "";
  int x = 0;
  String[] arr = new String[x];
  
  while (!vendedor.equals("end"))
  {
    System.out.print("Vendedor: ");
    vendedor = ler.next();
    
    for (int indice = 0; indice < arr.length; indice++)
    {
      arr[indice] = ler.next();
      System.out.print(arr[indice]);

    }
  }
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: traduz a tua pergunta para que alguém te possa ajudar. O nosso site é português.

Comment: Não seria melhor criar uma classe e passar os clientes?. Tem que ser um array mesmo?

Comment: @R.Galamba já traduzi, obrigado!

Comment: @IgorVargas sim, tem que ser um array. É para um trabalho da faculdade e estamos a ser obrigado a fazer em array.

Comment: Não sei exatamente como seu professor quer mas existe o Arraylist no java. Pesquise um pouco sobre ele. Caso não de para usa-lo. Da pra vc por um array dentro de um laço com um numero grande e ir colocando os nomes dentro e quando a pessoa digitar um numero ele sai do laço.

Comment: Se nao é possivel saber a quantidades de strings a serem guardadas, array nao serve, pois ele é finito e precisa saber seu tamanho quando é iniciado. O que poderia fazer, que seria uma gambiarra pessima por sinal, é verificar se o array chegou ao indice final, e criar outro maior repopulando o menor nele.

Comment: @ArticunoL então não é possível o utilizador do programa inserir os nomes e no final o programa ler e armazenar esses nomes sem que eu tenha posto um limite do array?

Comment: Por favor, releia o que eu expliquei. Eu não quis dizer isso. Você quer armazenar uma quantidade que não sabe definir de indices no array, mas o array precisa ser iniciado com um tamanho OBRIGATORIAMENTE antes de ser usado para armazenar algo. Se voce nao sabe o tamanho, deve usar ARRAYLIST, que se adequa automaticamente conforme a quantidade de itens adicionados.

Comment: @ArticunoL Obrigado!

Comment: Agora se o exercicio exige array sem collections, vai a sugestao do meu primeiro comentario, que é criar um mecanismo que, antes de salvar uma nova strings, controle o tamanho do array, se chegar ao ultimo indice, cria outro maior e repopula os dados nele, adicionando a nova string após isso.

Answer (score 2):

Vou deixar minha contribuição mais como uma alternativa, pois não sabemos se seu professor aceitará o truque com `split()`.

Usei sua idéia de impor um limite baseado no tamanho do array.

Assim digamos que vc crie, por exemplo, um array com tamanho 10.

Se vc inserir apenas 5 nomes, no final ele imprime apenas os 5 nomes.

Se inserir 10, que é o limite no exemplo, o loop pára automaticamente e imprime os 10 nomes.

Aí cheguei nisso:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tamanho = 3;
    int indice = 0;
    String[] arr = new String[tamanho];

    while (indice != tamanho)  {
      System.out.print("Vendedor: ");
      String vendedor = ler.nextLine();

      if (vendedor.equals("end")) break;

      arr[indice++] = vendedor;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++)
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Guilherme Daniel

Pega tudo antes e depois passa para o teu array.

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public static String EXIT = "exit";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        StringBuilder bancoDeDados = new  StringBuilder(); 

        while (ler.hasNext()) {

            String str = ler.next();
            bancoDeDados.append(str + ",");         
            if(str.contains(EXIT)) break;           
        }

        int tamanhoDoArray = bancoDeDados.toString().split(",").length;
        String[] arr = new String[tamanhoDoArray];
        arr = bancoDeDados.toString().split(",");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nao sei se leu os comentarios, onde ele diz que apenas pode usar array.

Comment: @ArticunoL e agora chefe?

Comment: Gambiarra com split hein. Sem contar que vai adicionar EXIT no array.

Comment: depois refatora

Comment: O objetivo do campo resposta é dar uma solução plausivel. Se for pro autor ter que corrigir os erros da resposta, então na verdade você não estaria ajudando-o.

Comment: sim, ele quer resolver o trabalho escolar dele e no problema não esta claro se salva ou não o EXIT, é um trabalho escolar e não uma aplicação, ele consegue pincelar tranquilamente, deixa uma resposta ai tb e "ajuda!". @ArticunoL

Comment: Se nao está claro, nao acha que o correto é perguntar ele nos comentários do que dar uma resposta, que alem de conter alguns erros e gambiarras que podem passar o aprendizado errado pra ele?

Comment: Se nao reparou, foi exatamente o que eu fiz, ele nao respondeu, por isso nao respondi. Prefiro esperar esclarecimento para dar uma resposta correta e adequada do que responder de qualquer jeito.

Comment: ok professor, feliz ano novo.